# SAS Create a net columns by day - arrays

Tags: sql, arrays, sas

I need to create in SAS net columns of other columns group by day and customer. I don´t know how to use information data that is previous, maybe it will be useful with arrays.. but I don´t know accuracy the method.

Thanks in advance!

```
DATA have;
infile datalines dsd delimiter=',';
informat Effective_date1 ddmmyy10.;
format Effective_date1  ddmmyy10.;
input Agreement Customer    Effective_date1 Credit  Debit   Balance AmountArrears;
datalines;
1,0,01/01/2020,100,0,10000,0,           
2,0,02/01/2020,0,10,500,10,         
1,0,03/02/2020,0,50,10000,50,           
2,0,03/02/2020,0,10,490,20,         
1,0,05/02/2020,50,0,9950,0,         
2,0,05/02/2020,0,10,480,30,         
1,0,08/02/2020,0,30,9920,30,            
2,0,08/02/2020,30,0,450,0,          

;;;;
RUN;

DATA want;
infile datalines dsd delimiter=',';
informat Effective_date1 ddmmyy10.;
format Effective_date1  ddmmyy10.;
input Agreement Customer Effective_date1 Credit Debit Balance AmountArrears CreditNet   DebitNet    BalanceNet AmountArrearsNet ;
datalines;
1,0,01/01/2020,100,0,10000,0,100,0,10000,0,         
2,0,02/01/2020,0,10,500,10,0,10,500,10,     
1,0,03/02/2020,0,50,10000,50,0,60,10490,70,         
2,0,03/02/2020,0,10,490,20,0,60,10490,70,           
1,0,05/02/2020,50,0,9950,0,50,10,10430,30,      
2,0,05/02/2020,0,10,480,30,50,10,10430,30,          
1,0,08/02/2020,0,30,9920,30,30,30,10370,30,         
2,0,08/02/2020,30,0,450,0,30,30,10370,30,           

;;;;
RUN;
```

Comment: After sorting by `customer agreement Effective_date1`, I am unable to tell how you get to your net values. If you post what the formula should be to get each one, the solution should be pretty straignt-forward with some by-group processing and lag statements.

Answer (score 0):

Are your columns CreditNet, DebitNet, BalanceNet & AmountArrearsNet calculated correctly?  I don't see a logical formula, but I think this problem could be solved fairly easily with some a RETAIN statement on some calculated running totals.